# How do I publish to an On-Prem computer using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to use Azure DevOps to deploy to my client's on-prem computer.
I have been looking at [docs on build and release agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts)  At first I thought that maybe it was a "self-hosted agent" but after reading further I thought it might be [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=vsts). that I need. However deployment groups seem to be about VMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Azure DevOps portal   ( dev.azure.com)
Organization Settings > Agent pools > Default 
download the agent
make sure to use powershell not powershell ise